Solving $dx/dt=f(x)$ if $f(x)$ is piecewise linear
Suppose $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a piecewise linear continuous function and I want to solve the differential equation $dx/dt=f(x)$ with initial condition $x(0)=x_{0}$. My thought is: Suppose $f(x)=ax+b$ on some interval $(p,q)$ containing $x_{0}$. By using separation of variables, we can do
$$\int \frac{dx}{ax+b}=t,$$
assuming that $x\in(p,q)$. If it moves outside of the interval, then we do similar procedure again for different interval.
However, I want to find an explicit formula that I can use to feed into my python code. Is there a compact explicit formula (or close to it) for $x(t)$?

The linear first order equation $$f'= a f + b; \quad  f = c\ e^{a t} - \frac{b }{a} =  e^{a (t-s)} - \frac{b }{a} $$ has the free scaling parameter $c$ or time shift $s$, that have to be determined in such a way that the solution is continuous at any of the two equal intervall ends: $$  e^{a_n (t_n-s_n)} - \frac{b_n }{a_n}=e^{a_{n+1} (t_n-s_{n+1})} - \frac{b_{n+1} }{a_{n+1}}$$
As a set of inhomogenuos tanscendental equations for exponentials only numerical procedures can  be used.
